# Android RPi bluetooth disconnects after pairing

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3b+, android

I'm trying to set up some simple communication between my RPi 3B+ and my phone One Plus 3, but when I try to pair the RPi, it gets disconnected a few seconds after pairing, and disappears from "Paired devices" list on my phone. If I try to pair from RPi (using scan on and connect) I get disconnected the same way. Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: I'm running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:62:B9:EB raspberrypi [default]
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:62:B9:EB Discoverable: yes
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[NEW] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 OnePlus 3
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 466709 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 Modalias: bluetooth:v001Dp1200d1436
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device C0:EE:FB:E1:BD:41 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

P.S. In the future I would like to do headless paring, haven't found any solutions for this yet.